# RemoteConfig.configValue(forKey:) returns default value

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm using Firebase Remote Config with Firebase A/B Testing on iOS.
I see a value received from Remote Config sometimes reset to default value.
I think, activated config values does not delete even if server cache on the app has expired.
Is there any situation that activated values are back to the default value?

- In-App: Default Value `A` set.
- fetch -> activate
- Got `B` from the server.
- Leave apps.
- Several hours later, I come back to the app, it seems the value is reset to `A`.

### fetch and activated a strategy

The app activates remote config values once at launch time.

- https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/firebase-remote-config-loading.html

  - Strategy #3: Load values for next time

> When your user starts up your app, you immediately call activateFetched(). This will apply any old values you've previously fetched from the cloud. And then your user can immediately start interacting with your app. In the meantime, you kick off an asynchronous fetch() call to fetch new values from the cloud. And in the completion handler for this call… you do nothing. Heck, you don't even need to add a completion handler in the first place. Those values you fetched from the cloud will remain stored locally on the device until your user calls activateFetched the next time they start your app.

### ABTesting Settings

- target user: 100% of the app
- variant-key -> `SOME_KEY`
- Control Group: 50% -> value = `A`
- Variant B: 50% -> value = `B`

### Pods versions from `Podfile.lock`:

```
  - FirebaseABTesting (2.0.0):
  - FirebaseRemoteConfig (3.1.0):
```

### How to set defaults, get values

Default Value is:

```
RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().setDefaults(["SOME_KEY": "A"])
```

To get Value from Remote Config:

```
let value = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configValue(forKey: "SOME_KEY")
```

### App Launch Sequences

- At first app launch

  - `activateFetched()`
  - got value `A`(=default).
  - There is no fetched value yet, `activateFetched` has no effect.
  - then fetch.
- next time app launch

  - `activateFetched()`
  - got value `B` (if the user is selected ABTestring's value 'B')
  - then fetch.
- next time app launch

  - `activateFetched()`
  - got value `A` (this is the issue)
  - then fetch.

In the above situation, if the app fetched and activated value `B`,
the value is persisted in activated values cache and
the cached value doesn't reset to `A` I thought.
Is the assumption right?

### Addtional Info

When the app got `B` from `configValue(forKey: "SOME_KEY")`
then `remoteConfig.allKeys(from: .remote, namespace: NamespaceGoogleMobilePlatform)` returns `["SOME_KEY"]`.

But when the app got `A` back from 'B' (the last situation in above launch sequence),
then `remoteConfig.allKeys(from: .remote, namespace: NamespaceGoogleMobilePlatform)` returns empty.

Comment: Did you got any solution ?

Comment: Did you solve this?